# Investigating JSON data

Tags: python, json

## PowerShell

Here's an API call to sec.gov in Windows PowerShell:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001318605.json" -UserAgent 'company user@abc.com'
```

If you want to try the call, replace `company user@abc.com` as appropriate.

If we look at `$result`, by default, it shows the property names as well as a brief representation of the values:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> $result


cik                               : 1318605
entityType                        : operating
sic                               : 3711
sicDescription                    : Motor Vehicles & Passenger Car Bodies
insiderTransactionForOwnerExists  : 0
insiderTransactionForIssuerExists : 1
name                              : Tesla, Inc.
tickers                           : {TSLA}
exchanges                         : {Nasdaq}
ein                               : 912197729
description                       :
website                           :
investorWebsite                   :
category                          : Large accelerated filer
fiscalYearEnd                     : 1231
stateOfIncorporation              : DE
stateOfIncorporationDescription   : DE
addresses                         : @{mailing=; business=}
phone                             : 650-681-5000
flags                             :
formerNames                       : {@{name=TESLA MOTORS INC; from=2005-02-17T00:00:00.000Z; to=2017-01-27T00:00:00.000Z}}
filings                           : @{recent=; files=System.Object[]}
```

So, I can drill down into the `filings` and pipe it into `fl` to see what's in there:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> $result.filings | fl


recent : @{accessionNumber=System.Object[]; filingDate=System.Object[]; reportDate=System.Object[]; acceptanceDateTime=System.Object[]; act=System.Object[]; form=System.Object[];
         fileNumber=System.Object[]; filmNumber=System.Object[]; items=System.Object[]; size=System.Object[]; isXBRL=System.Object[]; isInlineXBRL=System.Object[]; primaryDocument=System.Object[];
         primaryDocDescription=System.Object[]}
files  : {@{name=CIK0001318605-submissions-001.json; filingCount=440; filingFrom=2005-02-17; filingTo=2015-06-15}}
```

And so on.

## Python

Let's make the equivalent call in Python:

```
import requests

url = "https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001318605.json"

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'company user@abc.com' }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

If we use `response.json()`, all the data is dipslayed:

```
response.json()
```

If I use `pprint`, it also displays all the data:

```
import pprint

data = response.json()

pprint.pprint(data)
```

## Question

Is there a way in Python to display only the top level properties and values in a table similar to the default PowerShell output?

Answer (score 2):

Try using pprint's depth argument.

```
import pprint
data = response.json()
pprint.pprint(data, depth=1)
```

Depth equals to the amount of levels you want to display. depth=1 should only show "top-level" data.

I recommend you to have a look at the pprint docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html